# Avoid requiring Dispatcher.BeginInvoke

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm writing a library to control an application over TCP.  The connections are handled asynchronously so I've added an event to the communication class to indicate a message has been received.

```
public event EventHandler<MessageRecievedEventArgs> MessageRecieved;
```

But when I raise the event the event handler in the main class executes the event handler on the TCP thread not the main thread.

**How do I avoid requiring the user to update the GUI by invoking?**

```
    private void MessageRecieved(object sender, MessageRecievedEventArgs e)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(()=> { textBox1.Text = e.Message; }));
    }
```

Comment: Short answer, you can't easily do that. If you're using WPF, you need to run the task on the UI thread, hence the dispatcher. Some detail as to the structure of your program would be useful, as would a more detailed explanation of what you are trying to do.

Comment: You definitely want the UI update to happen on the UI thread and also you don't want the library to know about your UI thread. What you can do is find an elegant way to bridge them. What worries you about the way you do it now?

Comment: @Ycoub Massad  it just seems messy to me to require the user to put in the overhead of using the Dispatcher.

Comment: If you think about it, the fact that you need to use the dispatcher is related to the client it self (the UI app). It is the UI app that has this special requirement. It is not the fault of the library. Other clients, e.g. console applications, don't have such special requirement.

Comment: That is a good point...

Comment: Copy SynchronizationContext.Current in your class constructor.  With the assumption that the client code will call it from the UI thread.  You can then, later, call its Send() or Post() method to get the event to fire on that UI thread if it isn't null.  The AsyncOperation class is a small helper class that does this, although it obfuscates what is going on a bit too much.

Comment: @HansPassant That works!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Hans Passant's comment above, I just modified my code as follows:

```
    private SynchronizationContext MainUIThread; //as a class field
```

In the constructor:

```
public MyClass()
{
      MainUIThread = SynchronizationContext.Current;
}
```

Modification to the event structure:

```
    public event EventHandler<MessageRecievedEventArgs> MessageRecieved;

    protected virtual void OnMessageReceived(object sender, MessageRecievedEventArgs args)
    {
        var handle = MessageRecieved;

        if (handle == null)
            return;

        if(MainUIThread  != null)
        {
            MainUIThread.Post(d => handle(sender, args), this);
        }
        else
        {
            handle(sender, args);
        }
    }
```